# Java JSTL - How to avoid ParseException for my code snippet?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I would like to know where I go wrong, when I add the sum of 1 to 100 and display it using JSTL.

Here is my code:

```
<c:set var="sum" value="0" />
<c:forEach var="num" begin="1" end="100" varStatus="status">
${sum = sum + num}
</c:forEach>
<c:out value="${sum}" />
```

When I am trying to execute the above code, I am getting the following Exception:

```
> org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "  "= "" at line 1, column 7.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<c:set var="sum" value="${sum + num}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
`<c:set var="sum" value="${sum + num}"/>`
     instead of 
`${sum = sum + num}`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following `static` method of the `Math` class.

```
 Math.round(25.5);
```